# Creating new objects in the body of a loop

Tags: java, object, for-loop

I am trying to write a very basic java  program that will run allow the user to enter information about some employees. What I have in mind is a for loop that will create a separate Employee object (of an Employee class, already defined) and then retain each object in memory after the entire loop has run. Something like this:

```
      String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many Employees are we "
         + "entering into the system?");
      int numEmployees = Integer.parseInt(input);

    for (int count = 1; count <= numEmployees; count ++)
    {
    Employee employee(count) = new Employee();
    }
```

I know this code doesn't work; but I hope it makes clear that what I am trying to do is: each iteration of the loop create a new object (employee1, employee2....employeeN) and then have some code that will allow the user to enter the needed data.I already have all the necessary accessor and mutator methods. The object would remain in memory after the loop is finished running.
Any ideas? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Use an array. Use an array. Use an array

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use an array

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[numEmployees];
for(int i = 0; i < numEmployees; i++)
    employees[i] = new Employee();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try storing it in some collection.

```
     List<Employee> employeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

     for (int count = 1; count <= numEmployees; count ++)
     {
        employeList.add(new Employee());
     }
```

or simply  in array.

```
         Employee[] employeList = new Employee[numEmployees];

         for (int count = 1; count <= numEmployees; count ++)
         {
            employeList[i]=new Employee();
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to create variable variable names, which isn't possible in Java. Instead, you should store your employees in an array.

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[numEmployees];
```

To add employees to the array, you can do this

```
employees[count] = new Employee();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array (in this case is good, because you already know how much employees you will have) or an ArrayList (dynamic size, better if you don't know how much elements it will contains).

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[numEmployees];
```

Then every cycle you should do

```
for (int count = 0; count < numEmployees; count ++)
{
    employees[count] = new Employee();
}
```

To create a new Employee and store it. Anyway i edited some parts of your code.

`count = 1` will be `count = 0`
Because arrays starts from 0

`count <= numEmployees` will be `count < numEmployees`
Since starts from 0, `<=` will go to `numEmployees` and arrays size is `numEmployees-1` it means "out of bounds" of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an java.util.ArrayList to store the Employee objects.  Your code may look something like this:

```
package EmployeeStuff; 

import java.util.ArrayList;

// rest of the class code 

ArrayList<Employee> emps = new ArrayList<Employee>();


String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many Employees are we "
     + "entering into the system?");
  int numEmployees = Integer.parseInt(input);

for (int count = 1; count <= numEmployees; count ++)
{
    emps.add(new Employee()); // add an employee object to the ArrayList 
}
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you were getting to. Make an empty array of Employees and then assign then in turn inside the loop. You could alose opt for an ArrayList as in the other answer.

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many Employees?");
int numEmployees = Integer.parseInt(input);

Employee[] employess = new Employee[numEmployees];
for (int count = 0; count < numEmployees; count ++)
{
    employees[count] = new Employee();
}
```

Comment: Array indexes start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class EmployeeService
{
    public static List<Employee> createEmployees(int numberOfEmployees)
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfEmployees;i++)
        {
            Employee e = newEmployee();

            // gather required employee information

            employees.add(e);
        }

        return employees;
    }

    /**
     * Create an in-memory employee object.
     *
     * @return  in-memory employee object
     **/
    public static Employee newEmployee()
    {
        return new Employee();
    }
}

class Employee
{
}
```